# Unable to connect to Postgres from a Docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I have two containers on a server, one running a Postgres instance from a docker container.

[image]

However, I can't seem to be able to connect to PG from inside either of the containers, it just times out.

I've tried `docker exec -it backend bash` followed by:

- `psql --host <server_ip> --port 8080 -U root -d main`, which locally prompts for password, but times out here.
- `python` then
  [image]
  which prints connection info locally and on the server shell, but not from inside the container (exception raised after around a minute).

More info:

- `docker logs postgres` doesn't show anything helpful.
- mtu is 1500 for docker0, eth0, and eth1.
- The server is a basic droplet on Digital Ocean.

Comment: How did you run both containers? Probably they run on separate network. Consider using docker compose instead. Have a read at the compose networking docs.

Comment: I think you are trying to connect to port 8080 whereas Postgres works on port 5432. Try changing your port to 5432. Is your port being forwarded to 5432, check that part also

Comment: @gerrytan can you clarify what you mean by separate network? They're on the same server and are both accessible via <server_ip>:<port>.

Comment: @AnujPanchal You can see in the first screenshot that it's mapped, and I can connect to the DB with psql locally with `<server_ip>:8080` so it's not the port.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve]: as @gerrytan suggests, include either the `docker run` commands or `docker-compose.yml` file that start the container(s), what connection information you're using to try to connect to the database, and the exact error you're getting.  [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  When you update the question, make sure to include the code and error messages in plain text.